# how to write a query to filter the multiple input field of account

Tags: apex, query, filters

```java
public with sharing class SearchComponent{
  @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
  public static List<Account> getAccountList(String searchKey) {
    String key = '%' + searchKey + '%';
      return [SELECT Id, Industry, Type, Rating, AnnualRevenue,Website  FROM Account  WHERE **Type, Rating ,Industry = searchKey** LIMIT 10];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming either of Type, Rating or Industry can match with  search key then you can write query as below

```
[SELECT Id, Industry, Type, Rating, AnnualRevenue,Website  FROM Account  WHERE Type like: searchKey or Rating like: searchKey or  Industry like: searchKey LIMIT 10];
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the [LIKE](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_comparisonoperators.htm) operator.
If at least one field should match with the filter, you must put those clauses in OR:

```java
public with sharing class SearchComponent{
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Account> getAccountList(String searchKey) {
        String key = '%' + searchKey + '%';
        return [SELECT Id, Industry, Type, Rating, AnnualRevenue,Website
                FROM Account
                WHERE Type LIKE :key OR Rating LIKE :key OR Industry LIKE :key 
                LIMIT 10];
    }
}
```

I would suggest these trailheads: [SOQL for Admins](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/soql-for-admins) and [Apex Basics & Database](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_database)